# Codeigniter 2.x website is not executing methods after migrating to CentOS + WHM server

Tags: caching, codeigniter-2, centos6, whm

Folks,

We have a website running with CodeIgniter 2.x optimized with PHP 5.3.x when it was developed some 3-4 years back. It was very stable for few years until we didn't migrate it to a new Server based with CentOS + WHM + PHP 5.5.x. I tried talking to GoDaddy if they can downgrade the server to PHP 5.3.x but they refused to do that.

Interesting is, after migration, website still running fine and users can login and browse all the functionality etc but when a request is generated to manipulate / CRUD database then nothing happens except returning to that very same page without any update. Right after a CRUD request, pressing CTRL+F5 does the magic and the request gets a success. I tried making the requests by opening Console in Chrome browser by enabling 'Disable Cache' and everything works fine.

There is no Caching is setup under CodeIgniter nor under OS / WHM etc, I'm sure about that. I'm having no clue about the scenario.

Has anyone experienced the same ever or can suggest doing something to resolve the matter.

P.S: Another website developed with same Code-base / Architecture is running perfectly on the described new server.

Comment: It is your own VPS server running cPanel/WHM or you just have a shared hosting account on a GoDaddy server running WHM?!

Comment: Its a dedicated VPS.

Comment: btw, I had scripted the framework to disable the browser cache once a request loads into browser, it worked with normal requests.. but it discards and clear any attachments we submit with forms, so this fix also failing in some cases.